# GHC could not find module but GHCi can

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have previously installed the `tidal` package with `cabl install tidal`

When running `ghc Tidal.hs`:

```
Tidal.hs:4:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Sound.Tidal.Context’
    There are files missing in the ‘tidal-0.9.6’ package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Locations searched:
      Sound/Tidal/Context.hs
      Sound/Tidal/Context.lhs
      Sound/Tidal/Context.hsig
      Sound/Tidal/Context.lhsig
      /home/chris/.cabal/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.2.2/tidal-0.9.6-HlQOMGZHP8JDJBhFqbDzA/Sound/Tidal/Context.hi
  |
4 | import Sound.Tidal.Context
```

Within the last filepath that file indeed does not exist but there are files named that end in `.dyn_hi`. So the full path to the file that does exist is:
`/home/chris/.cabal/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.2.2/tidal-0.9.6-HlQOMGZHP8JDJBhFqbDzA/Sound/Tidal/Context.dyn_hi`

What may be the cause of the error? I am able to import the module successfully within `ghci`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read through this: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DynamicLinkingDebate

Running it with the `-dynamic` flag appears to fix it: `ghc -dynamic Tidal.hs`.